# Scaleway GLACIER class object storage with restic

Tags: backup

[Scaleway](https://www.scaleway.com) recently launched GLACIER class storage "[C14 Cold Storage Class](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/object-storage-glacier/)"

They have a great plan of 75GB free and I'd like to take advantage of this using the [restic](https://restic.readthedocs.io) backup tool.

To get this working I have successfully followed the S3 instructions for repository creation and uploading, with one caveat. I can not successfully pass the storage-class header as GLACIER.

Using awscliv2, I can successfully pass a header that looks very much like this from my local machine: `aws s3 cp object s3://bucket/ --storage-class GLACIER`

But with restic, having dug through some github issues, I can see [an option](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/706) to pass a `-o` flag. The linked issues resolution is not that clear to me so I have tried the following restic commands without successfully seeing the "GLACIER" class of storage label next to the files objects in the Scaleway bucket console:

- `restic -r s3:s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/restic-testing -o GLACIER --verbose backup ~/test.txt`
- `restic -r s3:s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/restic-testing -o storage-class=GLACIER --verbose backup ~/test.txt`

Can someone suggest another option?

Comment: Having thought about this, given restic needs to (I believe) understand the state of the repo i.e. the Scaleway object storage, using GLACIER is possible not going to work. Even if passing the GLACIER storage class flag was possible, the latency in checking the content of the bucket would be too large... Might need another back up option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm starting to use C14's GLACIER storage class with restic, and until now it seems be working very well.

I suggest to create the repository in the usual way with `restic -r s3:s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/test-bucket init`, which will create the `config` file and keys in the STANDARD storage class.
For backups, I'm using the command:

```sh
$ restic backup -r s3:s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/test-bucket -o s3.storage-class=GLACIER --host host /path
```

similar to what you did, apart the option is `s3.storage-class` and not `storage-class`.

In this way files in the `data` and `snapshots` directories are in GLACIER storage class, and you can add backups with no problem.
I can also mount the repository while data is in GLACIER class (I suppose all the info are taken from cache) so I can do `restic mount /mnt/c14` and I can browse the files, also if I cannot copy them or see their content.

If I need to restore files, I restore all bucket in STANDARD class with `s3cmd restore --recursive s3://test-bucket/` (see [s3cmd](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd)), I test that all files are correctly in standard class with:

```sh
$ aws s3 ls s3://test-bucket --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 4 | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "aws s3api head-object --bucket unitedhost --key '{}' | jq -r .StorageClass" | grep --quiet GLACIER
```

which returns true if at least one file is in GLACIER class, so you have to wait this command to returns false.

Obviously a restore will need more time, but I'm using C14 glacier as a second or third backup, while using another restic repository in Backblaze B2 which is a warm storage.

Comment: While this seems to work for a single backup, it looks like it breaks incremental backups. restic will create all objects with the GLACIER class, including indexes, locks and snapshots. I have patched my restic to apply the storage class only to data objects, but a more future-proof solution seems to be [this issue](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/3202) and [this merge request](https://github.com/restic/restic/pull/3235)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [vstefanoxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821238/vstefanoxx) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63704362/8251705) : Here is my workflow.

I setup the restic repository just like [vstefanoxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821238/vstefanoxx).

Now, if you want to **prune** the repository... you cannot as the files are in `glacier` and `restic` needs read-write access to the bucket to prune.
What is interesting about Scaleway is that file transferts between `glacier` and `standard` class are free. So let's move the data back to the standard class :

`s3cmd restore --recursive s3://test-bucket`

And wait until the end of the process using the command given by [vstefanoxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821238/vstefanoxx). Once your data is in the standard class it costs you five times more, so we have to be efficient :-)

So we now prune the repository:
`restic prune -r s3:s3.fr-par.scw.cloud/test-bucket`

And once it is finished, move everything (in fact `data, index` and `snapshots` but **not** `keys`) back to glacier:

```
s3cmd cp s3://test-bucket/data/ s3://test-bucket/data/ --recursive --storage-class=GLACIER
s3cmd cp s3://test-bucket/index/ s3://test-bucket/index/ --recursive --storage-class=GLACIER
s3cmd cp s3://test-bucket/snapshots/ s3://test-bucket/snapshots/ --recursive --storage-class=GLACIER
```

So we are now to a point where we have pruned the repository, trying to pay the least amount of money !

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer doesn't seem to work when doing incremental backups. I went with a different solution.

I set up a normal bucket, initialized with your usual `restic init`. Then I set up the following lifetime rule:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<LifecycleConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
        <Rule>
                <ID>data-to-glacier</ID>
                <Filter>
                        <Prefix>data/</Prefix>
                </Filter>
                <Status>Enabled</Status>
                <Transition>
                        <Days>0</Days>
                        <StorageClass>GLACIER</StorageClass>
                </Transition>
        </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

`Days` is set to 0, which means that the rule will be applied to all files. Rules are not applied continuously though, they're [applied once a day at midnight UTC](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/storage/object/api-cli/lifecycle-rules-api/#days).

This rule will only apply to the files in `data/`, which are the big files.

This rule description is supposed to be used with `s3cmd` but you can also do it from the dashboard if you prefer a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I search a solution to use Scaleway Glacier with restic with this idea :

All backup with date leather than 15 days in standard bucket and all backup with date between 16 to 90 days in glacier bucket

Aukfood